# c++: Use template default arugment and check if it is set explicitly

Tags: c++, templates

Edit: thanks for the prompt replies. I found my notation about `T` is confusing.
`T` is not a template argument but actual type hard coded in the switch clause, according to `case`.

I have the following template function that takes two template arguments, while the latter is optional:

```
template <typename F, typename RT = int>
pipe(Input input, F operation)
{
    // the Input is a container with its value stored in unknown type T
    // and I do the following switch to call different version of
    // operation (a template function as well) according to T
    switch (input.type())
    {
         case 0: RT output = (RT) operation<char>(input);break;
         case 1: RT output = (RT) operation<int>(input);break;
         ...
    }
    return output;
}
```

What I would like to achieve is to allow determine RT according to the parsed data type T when RT is not explicitly set, i.e.:

when call with `pipe<F>(input, operation)`, the return type would be the same as the data type of input;
when call with `pipe<F, RT>(input, operation)`, the return type would be set to RT regardless what input data type is.

I can achieve this for now by doing overloading, which involves copy paste the nearly the same chunk of code with a little modification

Therefore I am asking if there is a way to avoid this by having a special "dummy" type as the default RT:

```
template <typename F, typename RT = dummy>
```

and have some switch in the function `pipe` like this:

```
if (RT == dummy)
    // use T determined from switch as RT
else
    // use the specified RT
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You mean, you want to default to `T`?

Comment: Where does `T` come from ?

Comment: Partial specialisation (using a template struct) may solve your issue if `std::conditional_t<std::is_same<dummy, RT>::value, T, RT>` is not enough.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `template <typename F, typename RT = decltype(declval<F>()(declval<Input>()))>
RT pipe(Input input, F operation);` ?

Comment: Whatever else is true, the return type of a particular instantiation of `pipe` must be known at compile time. You seem to want to somehow defer it until runtime - that ain't gonna fly.

Comment: As hinted to by others, you should specialize this rather than switch on the type at runtime. That way, the compiler will pick the correct behavior at compiletime for you. Google template specialization if you're not familiar with this.

Comment: Wait a second.  You want the return type of a function to vary based on the run-time values of the arguments?  Are you ok with unions/variants?

Answer (score 1):

You should reverse your ordering. If you make the "dummy" template 2nd, to provide it explicitly, you will also have to provide the first type - and then you won't be able to take advantage of template deduction.

Instead, provide *two* overloads of `pipe`. One in which `RT` is explicitly provided:

```
template <typename RT, typename F>
void pipe(Input input, F operation) {
    switch (input.type())
    {
         case 0: RT output = (RT) operation<char>(input);break;
         case 1: RT output = (RT) operation<int>(input);break;
         ...
    }
    return output;
}
```

And one in which it's determined from `Input` and calls the other one:

```
template <typename F>
void pipe(Input input, F operation)
{
    pipe<typename Input::value_type>(input, operation);
     //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     //   or whatever metafunction
}
```

No `dummy` or need to avoid deduction necessary.

Comment: Implement one in terms of the other if possible.

Comment: @Yakk Yeah that's what I meant, if that wasn't clear.

Comment: @Barry @Yakk That was what I had originally. In your post, RT is actually my T, i.e. the type of the input data container. However, I wish I am able to vary the returned type of `pipe` according to another ''optional'' template argument, `RT` as denoted in my original post, so that if RT is explicitly set, pipe return type RT, otherwise return the same as T

Comment: Well, if you go and implement `pipe<RT>`, you end up repeating the `switch` statement, which I think the OP was trying to avoid.

Comment: In the op, the operation is dependent on the same switch.

Comment: @Yakk Oh I see now I think. Is the new edit along the lines of what the question is asking?

Comment: I *think* we need to pass the result of `input.type()` switch to type to operation as a template type argument.

Answer (score -1):

One thing that could actually help you, even if it doesn't answer your question directly is to use the internal typedefs of your container.
All the STL containers have a value_type alias which identify the element which are actually contained within.

Then you can call:

```
(RT) operation<input::value_type>(input)
```

Comment: I doubt OP uses syntax like `operation<T>(input);`, because it's not valid at all

Comment: if operation is the template of a functor that's perfectly valid.
The main issue in my opinion is that to switch among templates one should use template syntax not functional syntax (the switch construct)

Comment: `operation` is an instance of some deduced type `F`. even if it has a templated function call operator, it can't be called like that

Comment: Ah, in this sense you are right that you need to explicitly call the operator.

Comment: If you want to comment, earn enough rep and comment.  Don't comment in an answer.

Comment: If that was a reply to me I didn't get it. I think it could have been useful as an answer, even though there was an imprecision as I misunderstood part of the question.